# Dom-ready event after replaceWith

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

1. I add `textareas` to html-page by replacing a number of `divs` with .replaceWith() `JQuery` method.
2. I would like to make my `textareas` autogrow as user types there.

The problem is that autogrow library I use works only on dom-ready and thus I cannot apply my autogrow library to my `textareas` as they are generated dynamically.

Is there any kind of event after my `divs` are replaced with `textareas` that I can use to apply my autogrow library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use event handlers to capture changes to your textareas (even if they're generated dynamically), eg.

```
jQuery(function($){
    // dom ready
    $("body").on("input propertychange","textarea",function(event) {
        // here goes your autogrow code
    });
});
```

See it on action in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xmu9nu61/)

or here

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  // dom ready
  $("body").on("input propertychange", "textarea", function(event) {
    // here goes your autogrow code
    alert("changed");
  });

  $("#addTextArea").click(function(ev) {
    $("#textareas").append("<br/><textarea></textarea>");
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="textareas">
  <textarea></textarea>
</div>
<button id="addTextArea">Add textarea</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use JQuery [change()](https://api.jquery.com/change/).

That way, you can call your autogrow library when the user types something.

```
$("textarea").change(function(){
    //Your code here
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `$.holdReady()` then release the ready function once all of your DIVs are changed to textareas.

```
//code to prevent .ready() from firing
$.holdReady( true );

//code that releases (essentially triggers) .ready()
//use this in the callback function once your conversion 
//from DIVs to textareas completes
$.holdReady( false );
```

**[JSFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/su67rpbv/)** 
[jQuery.holdReady() reference](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.holdReady/)